# producing a cart array upon "add to cart" click on product

Tags: javascript, html, oop

I'm building this small cart project at the moment, however, when I'm passing the products to the cart class something strange is happening...

When I console.log() the products list in the cart class, I m getting separate arrays for each of the products. So for example, if I add 3 products from one product they get stored in a separate array see below in the screenshoot:

[image: Array display]

***Note: Please be aware that I clicked one each time and I'm expecting only one array with all the products I add to the cart.***

See the code below, including all the classes that are involved in this.

As Shown in console:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, productName: "Strawberry Basil", productImgURL: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/p…rry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png?v=1588713373", type: Array(3), price: 7}
1: {id: 1, productName: "Strawberry Basil", productImgURL: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/p…rry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png?v=1588713373", type: Array(3), price: 7}
2: {id: 1, productName: "Strawberry Basil", productImgURL: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/p…rry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png?v=1588713373", type: Array(3), price: 7}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
app.js:151 

(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 2, productName: "Sour Blueberry", productImgURL: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/p…rry_Still_4K_Front-SourBlueberry.png?v=1588713584", type: Array(2), price: 7}
1: {id: 2, productName: "Sour Blueberry", productImgURL: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/p…rry_Still_4K_Front-SourBlueberry.png?v=1588713584", type: Array(2), price: 7}
2: {id: 2, productName: "Sour Blueberry", productImgURL: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/p…rry_Still_4K_Front-SourBlueberry.png?v=1588713584", type: Array(2), price: 7}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

```js
// local Item List for development
const products = [{
    id: 1,
    productName: 'Strawberry Basil',
    productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png?v=1588713373',
    type: ['berry', 'citrusy', 'fancy'],
    price: 7,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    productName: 'Sour Blueberry',
    productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/SourBlueBerry_Still_4K_Front-SourBlueberry.png?v=1588713584',
    type: ['sour', 'berry'],
    price: 7,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    productName: 'Blackberry Jam',
    productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/BlackBerry_Jam_Still_4K_Front-BlackberryJam.png?v=1595035965',
    type: ['berry'],
    price: 7,
  }
];

class SideCartDrawer {
  cartProducts = [];

  addToCart(product) {
    this.cartProducts.push(product);
    console.log(this.cartProducts);
    const productEl = document.createElement('div');
    productEl.textContent = 'product 1';
  }

  renderCart() {
    let cartEl = document.createElement('h2');
    cartEl.id = 'cart-list-empty';
    cartEl.textContent = 'Cart is Empty';

    return cartEl;
  }
}

//Single product rendering

class SingleProductRendering extends SideCartDrawer {
  constructor(productDetails) {
    super();
    this.product = productDetails;
    this.productElementTemplate = document.getElementById('item-main-template');
  }

  addProductToCart = () => {
    this.addToCart(this.product);
  };

  render() {
    const productTemplateEl = document.importNode(
      this.productElementTemplate.content,
      true
    );
    const productEl = productTemplateEl.querySelector('.single-product');
    productEl.id = this.product.id;
    productEl.querySelector('img').src = this.product.productImgURL;
    productEl.querySelector('h2').textContent = this.product.productName;

    const btn = productEl.querySelector('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.addProductToCart();
    });

    return productEl;
  }
}

//Product List Rendering

class ProductList {
  constructor() {
    this.fetchProducts();
  }

  fetchProducts() {
    this.products = products;
  }

  render() {
    const productListEl = document.createElement('section');
    productListEl.className = 'products-holder';
    productListEl.id = 'product-holder';
    for (let product of this.products) {
      const productEl = new SingleProductRendering(product);
      const productElRendered = productEl.render();
      productListEl.append(productElRendered);
    }

    return productListEl;
  }
}

//shop API - assemble

class Shop {
  render() {
    const renderHookProductList = document.getElementById('app');
    const cartHook = document.getElementById('cart-items-list');
    const productList = new ProductList();
    const productListRendered = productList.render();
    renderHookProductList.append(productListRendered);

    const cartItemDrawer = new SideCartDrawer();
    const cartDrawer = cartItemDrawer.renderCart();
    cartHook.append(cartDrawer);
  }
}

const shop = new Shop();
shop.render();
```

```html
<body>
  <template id="item-main-template">
            <article class="single-product">
                <div class="product-image-container">
                    <img class="tour-img" src="" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="product-title">
                    <h2></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                    <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </article>
        </template>
  <template id="item-cart-template">
            <article class="cart-item">
                <div class="side-cart-product-item">
                    <h3>product 1</h3>
                    <button class="trash-icon">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="side-cart-product-price">
                    <p>$40</p>
                    <div class="cart-qty">
                        <button class="qty-btn">-</button>
                        <span>0</span>
                        <button class="qty-btn">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </template>

  <header id="home">
    <nav>
      <button type="button" class="nav-toggle" id="nav-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
      <h1 class="header-title">RAINBOW SODAS UK</h1>
      <button type="button" class="nav-toggle" id="cart-drawer-open">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"
                        ><span class="cart-items-counter">0</span></i
                    >
                </button>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="side-menu" id="side-menu">
      <button type="button" id="drawer-close" class="drawer-menu-close">
                    <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
                </button>
      <div class="drawer-title">SODAS UK</div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li>
          <a href="#products-filter" class="nav-link">shop all</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#products-filter" class="nav-link">products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#about" class="nav-link">about us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-drawer" id="side-cart">
      <div class="cart-inner">
        <button type="button" id="cart-drawer-close" class="cart-drawer-close">
                        <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
                    </button>
        <div class="cart-drawer-title">CART</div>
        <section class="cart-items-list" id="cart-items-list"></section>
      </div>
      <div class="cart-footer">
        <div class="total-display-side-cart">
          <h3>total</h3>
          <span>0</span>
        </div>
        <button class="checkout-drawer">checkout</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Please show the data hidden in the screenshot as text. Blind people, screen readers, search engines, and others can't read text in an image. Best is if you could use `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2))` and paste the result, since browsers tend to add a lot of cruft to the console.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please cut down on items and add relevan HTML and CSS to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan not sure why do you need the HTML and CSS class. This is mostly a problem with javascript code?

Comment: I need it to not have to EYEBALL debug your code!

Comment: ah! @mplungjan I have added the html! sorry, I very new to coding, just learning

Comment: Please look at the snippet  - I clciked edit, then scrolled down and clicked edit above snippet and pasted the HTML into the TOP frame!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to see if the cart already has the product

```
addToCart(product) {
  const cartProduct = this.cartProducts.find(item => item.id === product.id);
  if (cartProduct) {
    cartProduct.qty++
    }  
  else {
    product.qty = 1;
    this.cartProducts.push(product);
  }  
  console.log(this.cartProducts)
  const productEl = document.createElement('div');
  productEl.textContent = 'product 1';
}
```

```js
// local Item List for development
const products = [{
    id: 1,
    productName: 'Strawberry Basil',
    productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/Cherry_Pop_Still_4K_Front-CherryPop.png?v=1588713373',
    type: ['berry', 'citrusy', 'fancy'],
    price: 7,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    productName: 'Sour Blueberry',
    productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/SourBlueBerry_Still_4K_Front-SourBlueberry.png?v=1588713584',
    type: ['sour', 'berry'],
    price: 7,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    productName: 'Blackberry Jam',
    productImgURL: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0274/3641/7123/products/BlackBerry_Jam_Still_4K_Front-BlackberryJam.png?v=1595035965',
    type: ['berry'],
    price: 7,
  }
];

class SideCartDrawer {
  cartProducts = [];

  addToCart(product) {
    const cartProduct = this.cartProducts.find(item => item.id === product.id);
    if (cartProduct) {
      cartProduct.qty++
    }  
    else {
      product.qty = 1;
      this.cartProducts.push(product);
    }  
    console.log(this.cartProducts)
    const productEl = document.createElement('div');
    productEl.textContent = 'product 1';
  }

  renderCart() {
    let cartEl = document.createElement('h2');
    cartEl.id = 'cart-list-empty';
    cartEl.textContent = 'Cart is Empty';

    return cartEl;
  }
}

//Single product rendering

class SingleProductRendering extends SideCartDrawer {
  constructor(productDetails) {
    super();
    this.product = productDetails;
    this.productElementTemplate = document.getElementById('item-main-template');
  }

  addProductToCart = () => {
    this.addToCart(this.product);
  };

  render() {
    const productTemplateEl = document.importNode(
      this.productElementTemplate.content,
      true
    );
    const productEl = productTemplateEl.querySelector('.single-product');
    productEl.id = this.product.id;
    productEl.querySelector('img').src = this.product.productImgURL;
    productEl.querySelector('h2').textContent = this.product.productName;

    const btn = productEl.querySelector('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.addProductToCart();
    });

    return productEl;
  }
}

//Product List Rendering

class ProductList {
  constructor() {
    this.fetchProducts();
  }

  fetchProducts() {
    this.products = products;
  }

  render() {
    const productListEl = document.createElement('section');
    productListEl.className = 'products-holder';
    productListEl.id = 'product-holder';
    for (let product of this.products) {
      const productEl = new SingleProductRendering(product);
      const productElRendered = productEl.render();
      productListEl.append(productElRendered);
    }

    return productListEl;
  }
}

//shop API - assemble

class Shop {
  render() {
    const renderHookProductList = document.getElementById('app');
    const cartHook = document.getElementById('cart-items-list');
    const productList = new ProductList();
    const productListRendered = productList.render();
    renderHookProductList.append(productListRendered);

    const cartItemDrawer = new SideCartDrawer();
    const cartDrawer = cartItemDrawer.renderCart();
    cartHook.append(cartDrawer);
  }
}

const shop = new Shop();
shop.render();
```

```html
<body>
  <template id="item-main-template">
            <article class="single-product">
                <div class="product-image-container">
                    <img class="tour-img" src="" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="product-title">
                    <h2></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-btn-holder">
                    <button class="add-to-cart-btn" id="add-to-cart">add to cart</button>
                </div>
            </article>
        </template>
  <template id="item-cart-template">
            <article class="cart-item">
                <div class="side-cart-product-item">
                    <h3>product 1</h3>
                    <button class="trash-icon">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="side-cart-product-price">
                    <p>$40</p>
                    <div class="cart-qty">
                        <button class="qty-btn">-</button>
                        <span>0</span>
                        <button class="qty-btn">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </template>

  <header id="home">
    <nav>
      <button type="button" class="nav-toggle" id="nav-toggle">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
      <h1 class="header-title">RAINBOW SODAS UK</h1>
      <button type="button" class="nav-toggle" id="cart-drawer-open">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"
                        ><span class="cart-items-counter">0</span></i
                    >
                </button>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="side-menu" id="side-menu">
      <button type="button" id="drawer-close" class="drawer-menu-close">
                    <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
                </button>
      <div class="drawer-title">SODAS UK</div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li>
          <a href="#products-filter" class="nav-link">shop all</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#products-filter" class="nav-link">products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#about" class="nav-link">about us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-drawer" id="side-cart">
      <div class="cart-inner">
        <button type="button" id="cart-drawer-close" class="cart-drawer-close">
                        <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
                    </button>
        <div class="cart-drawer-title">CART</div>
        <section class="cart-items-list" id="cart-items-list"></section>
      </div>
      <div class="cart-footer">
        <div class="total-display-side-cart">
          <h3>total</h3>
          <span>0</span>
        </div>
        <button class="checkout-drawer">checkout</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for this. The quantity works, the problem now is that when I render those items in the UI, they are all show. My plan is to only allow one of each render in the cart drawer. Do you know how this could be achieved? the array keep showing separate as my initial problem. My idea is, if I have all items (duplicates and none duplicates) then I can apply a method to only have one of each.

Comment: I do not know what you mean. Please give a step by step on how to recreate what you see and what your expected output is.

Comment: when I add products to cart, the cart array, this.cartProducts is show like this in the console: [produc1] [product2] [product3], instead of [product1, product2, product3]. If I have all the products e.g. [product1, product 1, product 2, product 2] then I can filter duplicate out before rendering all products. A the moment, I can't do this.

Comment: I have added a new question about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65196894/how-to-avoid-product-duplicates-in-shopping-cart

Comment: Please only ask new questions if the old ones are done.

Comment: I managed to remove the previous child element on the child by adding this to the if statement you created if (cartProduct) {
    cartProduct.qty++; document.getElementById(`cart-${product.id}`).remove(); } thanks for your help btw